# Swift UserDefault stored array data load into UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

In my scenario, I am `storing` array data into `UserDefault` in `VC2`. In another `VC1` I am `retrieving` data. Now, I need to load data into `collectionview` array in VC1. Here, I am using multiple datasource Instead of that want to use single data source to get a specific values to load into collectionview. How to achieve this?

NOTE: while dismissing `VC2` I need to pass the array value to `VC1`

**Array Data Storing Into UserDefault in VC2**

```
let selectedData = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}
UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(selectedData), forKey:"sessiondata")
```

**Stored Data Retrieving In VC1**

```
    func storeValidaion(){
         // Retrive Array Values
          if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"sessiondata") as? Data {
               let sessionData = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<TeamListData>.self, from: data)
               print("ARRAY VALUES: \(sessionData!)")

          // here how to load array data into collection view

   if sessionData?.isEmpty == false {
            for person in sessionData! {
                print(person.userid!)

                if useridArray.contains(person.userid!) {
                    print("yes")
                } else {
                    self.useridArray.append(person.userid!)
                    self.nameArray.append(person.firstname!)
                    self.profileArray.append(person.profileimage!)
                    print(useridArray)
                    print(profileArray)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey:"sessiondata")
            self.useridArray.removeAll()
            self.profileArray.removeAll()
            self.nameArray.removeAll()
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    }

/*ARRAY VALUES: [ListData(userid: Optional("1"), firstname: Optional("abc"), designation: Optional("student"), profileimage: Optional("url"), isSelected: false), ListData(userid: Optional("2"), firstname: Optional("def"), designation: Optional("Executive"), profileimage: Optional("url"), isSelected: false)]*/
```

Comment: where are you using multiple dataSource?

Comment: **Never** use `value(forKey ...) as? Data`, there is `data(forKey`. And **never** misuse `UserDefaults` to share data between view controllers. Pass the data in the segue or after instantiation. And **never** ignore errors with `try?` when decoding Property List or JSON. And **never** use multiple arrays as data source.

Comment: @vadian but I have to maintain cache. That is the reason I used userdefault.

Comment: You can use `UserDefaults` to **save** the data, but not to **share** the data. The `UserDefaults` database is updated asynchronously, so you could get wrong data back.

Comment: @vadian Thank you so much. Could you please post some alternative code for me.

Comment: @isodev, What problem you facing here??

Comment: The alternative suggestions are in my first comment. The proper way to share the data depends on your design. For a single data source declare a property `var sessionData = [TeamListData]()` and decode the property list directly into that property.

Comment: @YagneshDobariya I need to use single data source instead of multiple datasource `self.useridArray`, `self.nameArray`,  `self.nameArray ` for loading data into CollectionViewCell.

Comment: @vadian I am using present model. Once user stored data into VC1 if they close VC1 then it will dismiss and show VC2 (Main VC). Here, I need to maintain cache data because in VC2 (MainVC) I am appending data into collection view. Supposed after selection user close and reopen app based on cache, the last selected data will be show in collection view.

Comment: Once again you can save updated data from everywhere to `UserDefaults` but you are strongly discouraged from using it to share the data. A modal presentation gives you direct access to the destination view controller so just hand over the data source array.

Comment: @vadian Okey I will pass the data from VC1 to MainVC. In MainVC again I need to store collectionview data otherwise if I close and open my collection view data will be empty right. I will try now.

Comment: @iosdev, show code of cellForItemAtIndexPath method...!!!

Comment: @iosdev create an sessionData as a instance variable instead of useridArray, profileArray, nameArray, and use the same.

Comment: @SGDev Please provide some code. Exactly what I am expected that's the point your advising me. but one more thing as per the vadian advice I think I need to pass the value from VC1 to MainVC, because sometime userdefault may have a chance to provide wrong data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code inside VC2

**Array Data Storing Into UserDefault in VC2**

```
let selectedData = membersData.filter{$0.isSelected}
UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(selectedData), forKey:"sessiondata")
```

adopt VC2Delegate

```
func dismissProtocole(data: Any) {
        <#code#>
    }
```

**Present VC2 inside VC1**

```
if let details = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC2") as?VC2 {
            details.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
             details.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            **details.selectedData = selectedData** // pass data
             details.delegate = self
            self.navigationController?.present(details, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

**Inside VC2**

var selectedData : [TeamListData]? // instance method 
  var delegate : VC2Delegate?

**Stored Data Retrieving In VC2**

```
func storeValidaion(){
        // Retrive Array Values
        if selectedData == nil  {
            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"sessiondata") as? Data {
                guard let sessionData = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<TeamListData>.self, from: data) else {
                    return
                }

                print("ARRAY VALUES: \(sessionData)")
                self.selectedData = sessionData
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                // put your code whatever you want....
            }
        }

    }
```

**Dismiss method**

```
func dismiss() {
    self.delegate?.dismissProtocole(data: sessionData)
}
```

**Protocol declaration**

```
protocol VC2Delegate {
    func dismissProtocole( data : Any)
}
```

Comment: `VC2` dismiss time I need to pass array value to `VC1`. But above code you mentioned all data pass during presenting time. Could you please update your code.

Comment: `storeValidaion` (even with the missing `t`) is pointless if the array is passed directly.

Comment: @iosdev why do you need to pass at the time of dismiss, VC1 already have the data.

Comment: @SGDev `VC2` I am storing data into UserDefault and then retrieving data into `VC1` Instead of that I need to pass the array value from VC2 dismissing time to `VC1`. The value passing we are doing for exact data. Because we may have a chance to get wrong data sometime. which is vadian trying to explain.

Comment: @iosdev use delegate to pass the data back to VC1

Comment: @SGDev if you don't mind could you please update your code. Just I would like to pass the array value from `VC2` to `VC1` while dismissing `VC2`. This is I am doing instead of storing and sharing data via UserDefault.

Comment: @SGDev Don’t do that (delegate), it’s another bad practice. The controllers are related, you got even the reference to the presenting view controller.

Comment: @vadian sure we can use this approach as well.

Answer (score -1):

**Save Data with Archive and fetch data with Unarchive in UserDefaults**

```
 func saveCustomData() throws {
    let array = ["New","Old"]
    let encodedData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "data")
}

func retrieveData() throws {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "data"),
        let dataArr = try  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [String] {
    } else {
        print("There is an issue")
        self.saveCustomData()
    }
}
```

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` is inappropriate for structs.