# How to maintain UICollectionView Data Cache after app close and open using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my scenario, I am trying to maintain `cache` data for `UICollectionView`. Here, `VC2` to `VC1` I am passing array data and `VC1` I am loading passed data into UICollectionView. Now, If I close and reopen app then I can’t able to see UICollectionView data Its all removed but I have to maintain cache. How to do it?

**Collection View Data Load From VC2 passed array**

```
 func pass(data: [TeamListData]) {
        print("ARRAY DATA RECEIVED:\(data)")
        participantsData = data
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

**My Array Data**

```
ARRAY DATA RECEIVED:[TeamListData(userid: Optional("1"), firstname: Optional(“abc”), designation: Optional("Analyst"), profileimage: Optional(“url.jpg"), isSelected: true), TeamListData(userid: Optional(“2”), firstname: Optional(“def”), designation: Optional("Executive"), profileimage: Optional(“url.jpg"), isSelected: true)]
```

Comment: yesterday, same question is asked by you . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730083/swift-userdefault-stored-array-data-load-into-uicollectionview

Comment: @SGDev buddy this question I have received passed array now I need to store it into VC1 itself and need to maintain cache. Yesterday, which is I asked that is for UserDefault to share but I found it is bad practice so I decided to store and reuse after data passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saved your data after getting callback in VC1

Code

```
 func pass(data: [TeamListData]) {
        print("ARRAY DATA RECEIVED:\(data)")
        participantsData = data
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue( try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(data), forKey: "sessiondata")
    }
```

Inside viewDidLoad in VC1

```
func storeValidaion(){
        // Retrive Array Values
        if participantsData == nil  {
            if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"sessiondata") as? Data {
                guard let sessionData = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array<TeamListData>.self, from: data) else {
                    return
                }

                print("ARRAY VALUES: \(sessionData)")
                self.participantsData = sessionData
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `func pass(data: [TeamListData])` here I am receiving values from VC2 to VC1. Now, I need to store and load  it into collectionview array.

Comment: This is I placed into VC1 `func pass(data: [TeamListData]) {` in this function I am receiving array data from VC2. Now instead of direct loading into collection view array `participantsData = data` If I store into userdefauklt after that I load into collectionview will maintain my data persistence

Comment: @iosdev good approach is to reloadData and then save data. it is improve your User experience.

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking for a cache, but for a persistent storage. Depending on where your data is coming from and how good solution you need, you can either use the disk, UserDefaults or a database approach such as CoreData, Realm or others.

There's a handy tutorial with a lot of code here for storing custom objects in UserDefaults with NSCoding: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html

E.g.

Conforming to the NSCoding:

```
struct PropertyKey {
    static let name = "name"
    static let photo = "photo"
    static let rating = "rating"
}

class Meal: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let name: String
    let photo: UIImage
    let rating: Int

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
        let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage
        let rating = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.rating)

        // Must call designated initializer.
        self.init(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating)

    }
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
        aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
        aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.rating)
    }
}
```

Saving data:

```
private func saveMeals() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path)
    if isSuccessfulSave {
        os_log("Meals successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
    } else {
        os_log("Failed to save meals...", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
    }
}
```

Loading data:

```
private func loadMeals() -> [Meal]?  {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path) as? [Meal]
}
```

Realm on the other hand offers a lot of flexibility for a bit more time investment in learning a third party lib: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models